# Iterate tr fmod 2 in Jade

Tags: laravel-5

I have a problem for iterate td into tr using fmod() in Jade using elixir jade in Laravel 5

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
@foreach($fields_base as $field)
    @if(fmod($i,2))
        tr.left                 
    @else
        td.bold Name:
        td Smith
    @endif
    <?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach
```

But when jade compile this I have

```
@foreach($fields_base as $field)
    @if(fmod($i,2))
        <tr class="left"></tr>
    @else
        <td class="bold">Name:</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

The td not into tr, HOw I can make this in Jade template :( I need this result

```
@foreach($fields_base as $field)
    @if(fmod($i,2))
        <tr class="left">
    @endif
        <td class="bold">Name:</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
    @if(!fmod($i,2))
        </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Based this into this example:

```
if (fmod($num,2)) echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>" . $num . "</td>";
if (!fmod($num,2)) echo '</tr>';
```

Regards!

Comment: Is it just me or isn't there a difference between what you have and what you want?

Comment: Hi @Charlie, is different, because this return 
`<tr></tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<tr></tr>`

 and I need 
`<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>`
 so td into tr